# im not able to get top post titles in a subreddit reddit api

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reddit

im making a discord bot that displays the top post on the r/worldnews subreddit but i don't know how to get the title for the top post because its in a json array (I think)
basically I need the title of the top post as a javascript variable.

heres my code

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix} 1`)){
    console.log('promted') 
    const https = require('https');
https.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/top.json', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
      
    console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
    const {title} = JSON.parse(data);



  message.channel.send(title)

// message.channel.send(data[0].country_code);


  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
}
)}
```

Comment: can you show what the console .logs show?

Comment: it says that "title" is undefined and that discord cant send a empty message